# TensorFlow Batch Hessian

Tags: python, tensorflow, derivative

I'm building a neural network that must approximate some multivariate function, say *f(**x**)*. The loss function is defined as how close the second derivative of the network is to the function *f*. To do this, I must compute the Hessian of *f(**x**)*. I wrote a custom TensorFlow model that kind of looks like this

```py
class ApproximateModel(tf.keras.Model):
    @tf.function
    def f_true_hessian(x: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
        # Some function that should return the actual Hessian
        return x
    
    def train_step(self, data):
        # tf.get_shape(x) -> (batch_size, dimension_x)
        x = data[0]
        
        # Calculate loss
        with tf.GradientTape() as second_tape:
            with tf.GradientTape() as first_tape:
                first_tape.watch(x)
                second_tape.watch(x)
                
                f = self(x, training=True)
            
            f_x = first_tape.gradient(f, x)
            second_tape.watch(f_x)
        
        f_jacobian = second_tape.jacobian(f_x, x)
        # tf.get_shape(f) -> (batch_size, dimension_x, batch_size, dimension_x)
        
        # I want to get (batch_size, dimension_x, dimension_x) somehow..
        loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(tf.reduce_sum(f_jacobian, axis=[1, 2]) - self.f_true_hessian(x))))
        return loss
```

For the interested reader, the application of this type of network is to approximate PDE's as in [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.07469.pdf).

The code above works well in case I don't have a batch size. I can't figure out how to get the Hessian in case I have a batch of samples of **x**. How do I get my desired output, where only the Hessian of *dimension_x* is computed and the *batch_size* is omitted?

Comment: I encountered same problem